# Which element are we currently at in a "for x in y:" loop

Tags: python, list, loops

The python syntax of `for x in y:` to iterate over a list must somehow remember what element the pointer is at currently right? How would we access that value as I am trying to solve this without resorting to  `for index, x in enumerate(y):`

The technical reason why I want to do this is that I assume that `enumerate()` costs performance while somehow accessing the 'pointer' which is already existing would not. I see that from the answers however this pointer is quite private and inaccessible however.

The functional reason why I wanted to do this is to be able to skip for instance 100 elements if the current element float value is far off from the 'desired' float range.

-- Answer --

The way this was solved was as follows (pure schematic example):

```
# foo is assumed to be ordered in this example
foo = [1,2,3,4,5,6....,99,100]
low = 60
high = 70
z = iter(foo)
for x in z:
    if x < low-10
        next(islice(z,10,10),None)
    if x > high
        break
```

Comment: Why exactly are you avoiding the use of `enumerate()`? It's the cleanest (and simplest) solution, and this is exactly what it's designed for.

Comment: I assume (could be wrong) that enumerating the list costs performance and if the under the hood pointer knew the value I could gain performance by adressing it directly. I will add this to the original question so people know why I wanted to avoid `enumerate()`

Comment: @BasJansen `enumerate()` doesn't *"enumerate the list"*, it enumerates the iteration. It's equivalent to `i=-1; for x in y: i+=1; ...`

Comment: Can you tell us what you'd like to do inside the loop that requires you to know the "pointer"?

Comment: I wanted to display a progress bar by doing `print str(x / (len(y)/10))+"0%"` for every 10% of the iteration. I can easily fix this by using index instead of x after an enumeration but I was hoping I didn't need to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot. `for` uses the [Python iteration protocol](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterator), which for lists means it'll create a *private* iterator object. That object keeps track of the position in the list.

Even if you were to create the iterator explicitly with [`iter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter), the current position is *not* a public property on that object:

```
>>> list_iter = iter([])
>>> list_iter
<listiterator object at 0x10056a990>
>>> dir(list_iter)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__length_hint__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'next']
```

The point of the iteration protocol is that it lets you treat any sequence, even one that continues without bounds, in exactly the same way. It is trivial to create a sequence generator that *does not have a position*:

```
def toggle():
    while True:
        yield True
        yield False
```

That generator will toggle between `True` and `False` values as you iterate over it. There is no position in a sequence there, so there is no point exposing a position either.

Just stick to `enumerate()`. All that `enumerate()` has to do is keep a *counter*. It doesn't keep position in the wrapped iterator at all. Incrementing that integer does not cost you much performance or memory.

[`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) is *basically* this, [implemented in C](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/enumobject.c#l122):

```
def enumerate(sequence, start=0):
    n = start
    for elem in sequence:
        yield n, elem
        n += 1
```

Because it is implemented in C, it'll beat trying to read an attribute on the original iterator any day, which would require more bytecode operations in each iteration.

Comment: I am assuming that there is no way to skip X elements during the loop? That is the functional aspect I was hoping to 'do'.

Comment: @BasJansen: Then use a `while` loop instead, or create the iterator before you loop over it and call `next()` on the iterator *in* the loop: `iterable = iter(sequence)` then `for elem in iterable:` then `next(elem) # skip one element`.

Comment: That is similar to another question that I found on SO but for each element to be skipped it requires 1 subsequent `.next()` right? Python does not have some form of 100x .next() for instance?

Comment: @BasJansen: You can use `itertools.islice()` to 'slice' items from an iterable, but you then need to 'consume' those items still: `list(islice(iterable, 100)) # skip 100 items`. `.next()` is the method *on* the iterable in Python 2, in Python 3 it has been renamed to `.__next__()`, `next()` is the built-in function that'll work across both Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: I am noticing that doing this in a while loop (even with making it skip a lot of elements) is still slower than a for loop, is that possible or am I missing something?

Comment: @BasJansen: You still need to read the data from the file; just because you are ignoring it doesn't make the reads themselves any faster (they are already buffered). I don't expect the slice to be slower though.

Comment: The file reading is something that can't be avoided but I was expecting the while (with skipping elements from the array) would perform faster than a for (which would evaluate every element in the array). I'm also not quite sure about slicing however, Let's say I have 50 reference ranges for which I would loop through a list containing 10.000 actual values I would have to slice the 10k list 50 times? *confused look* PS: This must all seem really basic but I just can't get my C mind to deal with this (yet).

Comment: @BasJansen: The `for` loop just calls `next()` on the iterator in each loop; so forwarding the iterator in the loop means the `for` loop skips elements (because you already skipped them in the loop).

Comment: @BasJansen: File objects are just iterators and iterators are just one next value after the other.

Comment: @BasJansen: Why don't you join us in the [python chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) and we can help you figure things out more easily?

Comment: Yes but I do an evaluation for each element (inside the for loop itself) that is why I was hoping to gain performance by skipping elements (and thereby skipping my own evaluation).

Answer (score 1):

No, it uses the underlying **iterator**, which is not forced to keep track of a current index.

Unless you manually incerement a counter, this is not possible:

```
idx = 0
for x in y:
    idx+=1
    # ...
```

so, just keep with `enumerate()`

Answer (score 1):

That 'pointer' value is internal to whatever it is that created the iterator. Remember that is doesn't need to be a list (something that can be indexed), so if you really want the 'index', you will need to resort to using enumerate.

Answer (score 1):

This information is internal to the iterator and cannot be accessed. See here for a description of the [iterator protocol](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html). Essentially, the only publicly available member of the iterator is `next()` which raises a `StopIteration` exception once the range is exhausted.

Besides, `enumerate` is pretty efficient. It is the equivalent of writing

```
i = -1
for x in y:
  i += 1
  # do something with x and i
```